# Reactjs get URL pathname id

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I want to get `id` from URL to load data from API, using `React JS`

```js
let url = 'http://localhost:3000/View/22'; //window.location.href originally instead of this
let object = new URL(url);
let path = object.pathname
console.log(path) 
//

console.log(path.split('/').pop())
```

I can get this `id` by `split()` but it's seems dirty, right? Is there a clean way or native way to get this? Also I am wondering, maybe this is not right way to get `id` and pass it to `API` , am I right? maybe there will be security issue, if someone enter `/View/22/22/33/44/` it get `44` not `22`

I am new to React, is there native way or correct way to get page id, and pass it to API?

Comment: `but it's seems dirty, right?` Not really, there's nothing wrong with it. You could use regex for it if you really wanted, but that's no better or worse.

Comment: `there will be security issue, if someone enter /View/22/22/33/44/ it get 44 not 22` In this case access the values by index, not always by retrieving the final one

Comment: are you using `react-router` for your app?

Comment: @gnujoow yes I am

Comment: @dannycavanagh  You'll always get the first number value in your path ``object.pathname.match('[0-9]+')[0]``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `this.props.match.params.id`

```
const id = this.props.match.params.id;
console.log(id)
```

In router:

```
<Route exact path='/View/:id' component={View}></Route>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want to do is use something like [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start), define routes and get the parameters inside a component.

Answer (score 2):

if you are unsing `react-router` for your app, you can get your url parameter with `useParams()` hook.

check following link.
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 let url = 'http://localhost:3000/View/22';
 var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Comment: This doesn't solve this problem the OP mentions: `if someone enter /View/22/22/33/44/ it get 44 not 22`